# pyspark unscaled value too large for precision spark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, avro

I am trying to read avro files written by pyspark with different schema. Difference in precision of decimal column. Below is my folder structure of avro folders written by pyspark

```
/mywork/avro_data/day1/part-*
/mywork/avro_data/day2/part-*
```

below are the schema for them

```
day1 = spark.read.format('avro').load('/mywork/avro_data/day1')
day1.printSchema()
root
 |-- price: decimal(5,2) (nullable = True)

day2 = spark.read.format('avro').load('/mywork/avro_data/day2')
day2.printSchema()
root
 |-- price: decimal(20,2) (nullable = True)
```

While reading the whole dataframe (for both days)

```
>>> df = spark.read.format('avro').load('/mywork/avro_data/')
```

it is giving below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unscaled value too large for precision spark
```

Why pyspark doesn't implicitly considers the higher schema (backward compatible)

Comment: which version of spark?

Comment: I am using spark-2.4.4 with python 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark uses first sample record to infer the schema. I think, in your case that sample record is of `decimal(5, 2)` causing this exception.
Regarding your question-

> Why does pyspark doesn't implicitly considers the higher schema?

To achieve this, spark needs to read the whole data twice. first to infer schema and second for processing.
Imagine, even `df.limit(1)` will read whole file first to infer the schema and then to read 1st record if you go this way.

There is an option to specify `avroSchema` option as below -

```scala
 val p = spark
      .read
      .format("avro")
      .option("avroSchema", schema.toString)
      .load(directory)
    p.show(false)
```

but here each avro file inside `.load(directory)` should match the schema which is not the case here.

**`Alternative`**

read both the dataframe and then do union

Comment: Passing the dataframe schema explicitly sounds a little odd (though it worked) as avro already has schema embedded in them unlike csv.. Alternative looks like a workaround. Isn't there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way